# Export file with stored procedures from Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, reactjs, sql-server-2008-r2, sequelize.js

I have a database in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2. And I need to export ALL the stored procedures in this database using sequelize and Reactjs.

I don't know how to include more details because I am not familiar with these topics.

I need your help to tell me what should I exactly do and what topics I have to read?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for the procedure name its underlying code, then this will work:

```
select  sp.name as ProcedureName,
        sm.definition as ProcedureCode
from    sys.sql_modules sm
join    sys.procedures sp on sm.object_id = sp.object_id
```

Comment: It did work thank you! but not the full code of the procedure, could you explain this code to me please? @TodMeinke

Comment: @AreejQadomi The full code is in the 2nd column.  If you copy a cell from that column and paste it into notepad or something like that, you'll see the full code.